# How to record intents from buttons in Adaptive cards, developed using custom json templates from Rasa custom actions?

Tags: chatbot, adaptive-cards, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

Please do suggest if worked with developing adaptive cards from Rasa to MS Teams API: how to record the `intent`, when a user presses the buttons in the Adaptive cards in Teams!

I could easily do that with defining `intent` value to `payload` using below code

```
dispatcher.utter_message(
    text="Please make your selection", 
    buttons = [
        {
            "type": "messageBack", 
            "payload": "/Intent1", 
            "title": "Button1"
        },
        {
            "type": "messageBack", 
            "payload": "/Intent2", 
            "title": "Button2"
        }
    ]
)
```

But as we know, to render these adaptive cards in Teams API, one needs to pass `json_message` in the `actions.py`, the one in my case is

```
nm = {
    "attachments": [{
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
        "content": {
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "version": "1.0",
            "body": [{
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "So, would you like to programme?"
            }],
            "actions": [{
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Button1"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Button2"
                }
            ]
        }
    }]
}

dispatcher.utter_message(json_message = nm)
```

Suggestions are welcome! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out, posting here the required template with [imBack card action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions?tabs=json#adaptive-cards-with-imback-action).

```
{ 
    "type": "Action.Submit", 
    "title": "Button", 
    "data": {
        "msteams": { 
            "type": "imBack", 
            "value": "/intent" 
        } 
    }, 
    "style": "positive" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [messageBack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions?tabs=javascript#adaptive-cards-with-messageback-action) with `displayText` key for message appearance when user click on the button and `text` key for intent and entities payload send to Rasa server.

```
{
    "type": "Action.Submit",
    "title": "My MessageBack button",
    "data": {
        "msteams": {
            "type": "messageBack",
            "displayText": "I clicked this button",
            text: '/intent_name{"entity":"entity_value"}'
        }
    }
}
```